# receive json with jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, api, jsonp

Can someone help me to receive this json with jquery?

```
{
"output_type":"json","diagnostic":{"status":"200","elapsetime":"0.4187","memoryusage":"17.91MB","confirm":"success","lang":"id","currency":"IDR"},"results":{"result":[{"id":"business:3772","label":"Puri Maharani Boutique Hotel & Spa - Denpasar, Denpasar Timur, Kesiman Kertalangu","value":"Puri Maharani Boutique Hotel & Spa","category":"Hotel"},{"id":"business:3852","label":"Maharani Hotel  - Jakarta Selatan","value":"Maharani Hotel ","category":"Hotel"},{"id":"business:3874","label":"Maharadja Hotel - Jakarta Selatan, Mampang Prapatan, Tegal Parang","value":"Maharadja Hotel","category":"Hotel"},{"id":"business:4776","label":"Pita Maha Resort and Spa - Gianyar, Ubud, Ubud","value":"Pita Maha Resort and Spa","category":"Hotel"},{"id":"business:4779","label":"The Royal Pita Maha Resort and Spa - Gianyar, Ubud, Kedewatan","value":"The Royal Pita Maha Resort and Spa","category":"Hotel"},{"id":"business:18420","label":"Villa Mahapala Bali - Denpasar, Denpasar Selatan, Sanur","value":"Villa Mahapala Bali","category":"Hotel"},{"id":"business:105246","label":"Mahagiri Dreamland Villas &amp; Spa - Badung, Kuta Selatan, Pecatu","value":"Mahagiri Dreamland Villas &amp; Spa","category":"Hotel"}]},"token":"bc8d3a106572e4cff038261afb568ecf"}
```

I use $.getJSON and $.ajax function but some problem occured,can someone help me with some jquery code?

this is my code,

```
function getAPI() {
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.master18.tiket.com/search/autocomplete/hotel?q=mah&token=90d2fad44172390b11527557e6250e50&secretkey=83e2f0484edbd2ad6fc9888c1e30ea44&output=json',
        beforeSend: function(x) {
            if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
             x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
            }
        },
            type:"get",
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain: true,
         success: function(data) { console.log(data); }
         });
    }
```

but the error is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: What problem occurs? Share more javascript code. Like the ajax call.

Comment: actually, i try this code..


function getAPI() {
      jQuery.ajax({
         url: 'http://api.master18.tiket.com/search/autocomplete/hotel?q=mah&token=90d2fad44172390b11527557e6250e50&secretkey=83e2f0484edbd2ad6fc9888c1e30ea44&output=json',

  beforeSend: function(x) {
       if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
         x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
        }
   },
         type:"get",
         dataType: 'json',
         crossDomain: true,
         success: function(data) { console.log(data); }
      });
 }

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to be tagged with `jsonp`, so I suspect that you are attempting to perform a cross domain AJAX call. If this is the case you could indeed use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) if the remote server supports it.

So if you are not doing a cross domain AJAX call:

```
$.getJSON('/script', function(json) {
    // TODO: manipulate the result here
});
```

and if the remote server supports JSONP:

```
$.getJSON('http://example.com/script?callback?', function(json) {
    // TODO: manipulate the result here
});
```